# Junction table in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, many-to-many, junction-table

Well, I am trying to build an application which allows to exchange messages between instructors and students. And I need to build a `ContentProvider` class, but I have encountered a problem how to represent a many-to-many relationship between the `Instructor` and `Student` classes, well it's more confusion than a problem.

I know that I need to create a junction table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE InstructorStudent (
Student INTEGER REFERENCES Student (student_id),
Instructor INTEGER REFERENCES Instructor (instructor_id),
PRIMARY KEY (student_id, instructor_id))
```

But, I have a question: is it considered a bad practice if I make the primary key of the junction table as a simple integer which automatically increments itself?

**Extra question**

How do I retrieve the list of students for a particular instructor, and vise versa?

Comment: Are you looking for MySQL, Java, or something else?  The primary key of the junction table should be the combination of `student_id` and `instructor_id`.  This probably won't change just because you are using MySQL from Android.

Comment: No, I'm using SQLite. I'm sorry for confusion, it should have been SQLite tag instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need an auto-incrementer for the join table. As long as the instructor id and student id are both unique you are fine.

> How do I retrieve the list of students for a particular instructor, and vise versa?

Lets say your student table is this `tbl_student`

Here is how i would write the query.

`select * from junctionStudentConstructor  where InstructorStudent.Instructor = insid;`

Replace insid with the instructor id.